# Как выровнять чексбоксы с их метками в одну строку

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Есть `CheckBoxList`.
Проблема в том что если `ListItem`(текст) много слов то текст отображается одну строку ниже своего чекбокса
Если у некоторых чекбоксов у которых текста меньше отражается нормально
Как решить проблему буду признателен за любые советы
Скрин к примеру так отображается:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно код, пожалуйста, и сделать его запускаемым?

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, ползуюсь bootstrap, там изменил display:inline-block на inline, стал норм отражать

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov, хочу сделать это для моего отдельного checkbox-а

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ничего не съезжало и выглядело аккуратно, можно воспользоваться flex свойствами. Это очень просто и отлично работает.

Суть в том чтобы контейнеру в котором содержится чекбокс и текст к нему (как правило это label) дать следующие свойства:

```
.checkbox-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Запустите демку ниже и посмотрите, устраивает ли вас такой результат. Надеюсь что помог. Удачи!

```css
.checkboxes {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 3px solid cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.checkbox-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkbox-group:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkboxes">
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-1" class="label">Текст в одну строку</label></li>
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-2" class="label">Текст в две строки. Текст в две строки. Текст в две строки.</label></li>
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-5" class="label">Текст в одну строку</label></li>
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-3" class="label">Текст в три строки. Текст в три строки. Текст в три строки. Текст в три строки. Текст в три строки.</label></li>
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-4" class="label">Текст в две строки. Текст в две строки. Текст в две строки.</label></li>
  <li class="checkbox-group"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-5" class="label">Текст в одну строку</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как использовал `bootstrap`, решено через класс `checkbox`

```
 <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не получается с flex, можно вручную отрегулировать vertical-align

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).